# How to detect intermittent time out problem in web applications?

Tags: java, web-services

Have a n-tire web application and search often times out after 30 secs.  How to detect the root cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log at separation of concerns, in this case at the boundaries of each layer.
when you say search, I'd assume that this is a web app where the user is searching for some text.

Is the DB search involved ?
Is there a possibility that your garbage collector is kicking in and the search timed out ?
Try to log your garbage collection pauses using java command line switches. Later, you can analyse when your JVM was doing GCs. OR you can use a tool like JConsole or JvisualVM.

BR,
~A

Answer (score 0):

You can add trace code to log its activities and then look at each operation to see what part times out and why.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tool [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html).

Install this tool on each tier and watch the http traffic and packets. This worked for me when debugging a time out issue which actually turned out to be an issue with empty SOAP envelopes.

Doing this will at least tell you which tier the issue is with.